# How do I expand the number of documents viewed in robo3t when running a MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb, collections, robo3t, updatebatchsize

I can only view 50 documents in document viewer. I have tried changing the 50 in the right hand corner to a larger number to expand the doucment view however this does not work. How do i increase the batch size?

[Example of 50 document batch size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBdyQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well i tried same i changed 50 to 100 and then clicked on the arrow key on right (in the attached image). I was able to see 100 records.